# I can get 400 error but there is no json object with ServiceStack fluent validation

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

Check List:

- Dto is X
- Response object is **XResult**:IHasResponseStatus and it is in the same namespace with X
- XValidator:AbstractValidator is working. I can get 400 error when sent invalid object
- Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
- container.RegisterValidators(typeof(X).Assembly);
- Accept    application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 in request headers.

I'm calling service from html. Validation framework is working but response is not json object. It is look like XML in firebug.

The part (that is responsible for catching error and serializing it to json) seems not working

Any guess?

**UPDATE**

**XResult** must be **XResponse**.. Thanks kampsj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, your response DTO should be named **XResponse** not XResult.  You have to adhere to the following convention for response DTOs

> {Request DTO Name} + Response

See https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Your-first-webservice-explained